# Starting to read from certain line in XMLREADER php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

XmlReader reads until the end of the document
How do i make xmlreader no to begin from the first line?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately XMLReader does not have a `seek()` method.